# Conversion error using pyodbc & CODEPAGE is not supported on the Linux

Tags: python, sql-server, linux, pyodbc

I am trying to save some data from file to database using pyodbc bulk insert.
I am getting a lot of these exceptions:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17
> for SQL Server][SQL Server]Bulk load data conversion error (type
> mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row
> 90411, column 3 (ARTIST_NAME).

I guess it could be caused by some speical chars like `%`, `ó`, `ś`. I could not even point all of them cause there is over 10 milions lines in a file. Is there any way to get rid of this exception?
My bulk insert looks like this:

> BULK INSERT someSchema.SomeTable FROM 'filePath'
> WITH (
> FIELDTERMINATOR='',
> ROWTERMINATOR='\n'
> );

I tried to add `CODEPAGE = '65001'` to this command but then I got

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Keyword or statement option 'CODEPAGE' is not supported on the 'Linux' platform. (16202) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Comment: Have you seen: [BULK with Codepage Parameter on Linux #289](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/289)?

Comment: Yes I have. I am not sure if solution with format file will help me cause topic's owner said that he could import data successfully - it just looked strange.